# Series expansion to lowest non trivial order over a list

Tags: series-expansion

I would like to imply `Series` to a list of experssions in such a way so that it expands each element of the list to the lowest non-trivial order

Example

```
ld={1/r, (r^2 + 4 y^2)/(4 - 2 M r + r^2)^2, 0, 4 - 4 y^2}
```

and what I want to do in an easy way is

```
Normal@{Series[ld[[1]], {r, Infinity, 1}], 
  Series[ld[[2]], {r, Infinity, 2}], 
  Series[ld[[3]], {r, Infinity, 0}], 
  Series[ld[[4]], {r, Infinity, 0}]}
```

which produces

```
{1/r, 1/r^2, 0, 4 - 4 y^2}
```

Comment: See also the elegant method (posted by an incredibly modest user) in [Series with a specified number of terms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/series-with-a-specified-number-of-terms/80108).

Comment: Hahah, I like that answer too. The titles of the questions made me believe they are not related, even though I saw them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often times it's most straightforward in Mathematica to start by automating exactly what you would do by hand, then see what type of adverse *use-cases* pop up.

In this case, you could try the lowest order and work up. Series expand to the $n$-th order with $n=0$. See if it worked and, if not, increasing `n++` until you get somewhere.

Something like this:

```
    firstNTSeries[expr_, {var_, var0_}] := Module[{n = 0, res}, 
            res =expr;
            While[expr =!= 0 && 
               Normal[res = Series[expr, {var, var0, n}]] === 0,
            n++]; 
            res // Normal]
```

Usage:

```
    firstNTSeries[#, {r, \[Infinity]}] & /@ ld
```

If you're getting bogged down by speed, (consider above applied to $(r^{10^{13}}+r^{10^{14}})^{-1}$), you can optimize at the cost of trusting `Series`' ability to guess the first nontrivial step. I.e. use the output of `Series` to change how fast you should be advancing $n$.  Something like:

```
    firstNTSeriesV2[expr_, {var_, var0_}] := 
          Module[{n = 0, res}, 
            res = expr;
            While[expr =!= 0 && 
                Normal[res = Series[expr, {var, var0, n}]] === 0,
                n = res[[5]]; 
            ]; 
            res // Normal
          ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking of doing something like that, but with `If` checks and it looked too cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ld = {1/r, (r^2 + 4 y^2)/(4 - 2 M r + r^2)^2, 0, 4 - 4 y^2};
MapThread[Normal[Series[#1, {r, ∞, #2}]] &, {ld, {1, 2, 0, 0}}]
```

> `{1/r, 1/r^2, 0, 4 - 4 y^2}`

Comment: Maybe I haven't expressed myself clearly, but the example I gave is random, in reality I want something that will not require me to type by hand the orders (which I wouldn't know anyway).

Answer (score 1):

```
powerlist = Map[Exponent[RootReduce[#], r] &, ld] /.{ -\[Infinity] -> 0,, _?Negative -> 1}
MapThread[Normal[Series[#1, {r, Infinity, #2}]] &, {ld, powerlist}]
```