# Vanishing order of a power series (or polynomial)

Tags: series-expansion

Is there a simple and efficient way to compute the vanishing order of a power series, i.e. the degree of its *smallest* nonzero coefficient?

It seems like this is a basic operation that should be built-in. (`Exponent[]` computes the *largest* coefficient.)

Ideally, this would be simple, readable, and work if called on a polynomial instead of a power series.

The best I've come up with so far is

```
(1+FirstPosition[CoefficientList[#, x], Except[0], 1, 1, Heads -> False])&
```

Which isn't great. An alternative, which seems ill-advised, is to force conversion to a power series and reach into the `SeriesData` representation.

```
(With[{ser = # + O[x]^20}, ser[[4]]/ser[[6]]]) &
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Try using Asymptotic, e.g., `Asymptotic[Cos[x]/Sin[2 x]^3, x -> 0]`

Comment: For a polynomial one can use `Exponent[poly,x,Min]`

Comment: @CarlWoll While this is a nice method there is an issue lurking. To wit, it will most likely use `Series` and apparently this is what the poster wishes to avoid.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote [my answer from this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/series-with-a-specified-number-of-terms/80108#80108), which solves your problem on the way to a different one:

> The leading-order power in your series should be the limit as $x \to 0$ of $x f'(x)/f(x)$.  So you could do something like
>
> ```
> leadcoeff = Limit[x func'[x]/func[x], x->0]
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, my power series are complicated. I wouldn't want to compute their derivatives, reciprocals, and then multiply them out, just to compute the vanishing order.

Comment: @user825383860:  Could you try it out and let me know how long it takes?  I would expect that Mathematica could take the derivative of a power series fairly quickly, and I would be surprised if it doesn't have L'Hopital-like tricks programmed in to find the limits of the ratios of polynomials and/or power series.

Comment: Also, if you want a solution that works well with your particular problem, it would be helpful to include code that generates the particular expressions you're working with.

Comment: I am trying to increase the performance of a power series algorithm by taking vanishing orders into account. This answer is unhelpful.

Comment: @user825383860:  With all due respect, it's hard to *be* helpful without more information about the problem you're trying to solve.  I would again encourage you to edit your question to provide more information about what you're trying to do;  providing sample code would be ideal.  Without that, I suspect the responses you get here will be off the mark like mine apparently is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for a simple example

```
poly = Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 3, 11}]
(* x^3 a[3] + x^4 a[4] + x^5 a[5] + x^6 a[6] + x^7 a[7] + 
 x^8 a[8] + x^9 a[9] + x^10 a[10] + x^11 a[11] *)
```

The built in `Exponent` returns the exponent of the highest order in `x`

```
Exponent[poly, x]
(* 11 *)
```

A simple change of variable, can give the lowest order in `x`

```
Block[{x = 1/z}, -Exponent[poly, z]]
(* 3 *)
```